# OkHttp certificate chain validation

Tags: ssl, okhttp

We are using Okhttp client to call other REST services.

Does OkHttp validate the entire certificate chain till the Root Certificate, when making an https call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OkHttp relies on the platform’s SSLSocket to do that in the handshake. The certificate chain is checked and its root must be trusted.